# Using "the" before this noun

Tags: articles

I have problem in recognizing when to use "the" before a noun. In this sentence:

> Another problem is **the** delay between devices.

Should I use **the** before **delay** or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because you are talking about one particular delay, and you are telling me which particular delay you are talking about - the one 'between devices'.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily correct.  If I had a complicated network of many devices with many different connections between them, all with different-sized delays, I could easily imagine saying, "Another problem is delay between devices," because I'm talking about the general problem of inter-device delay across the entire system, not any particular single delay between two particular devices.